# Unexpected string in JSON at position 22

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 22 
please help me!!!

package.json

```
{ "name": "restful-api",

 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
"author": "adem",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mysql": "^2.17.1"  }  }
```

Comment: Show us the JSON.

Comment: That' valid JSON, according to multiple validators. What **exactly** leads to the given error message?

Answer (score -1):

change "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" into "start": "nodemon index.js" and type "npm start" on the command line

Comment: PLease add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it